# opencart display_errors on, error_reporting = E_ALL

Tags: opencart

Opencart 3.0.2 with php.ini settings:

display_errors = 1;
error_reporting = E_ALL;

sometimes when the site is very busy, the browser display errors like database not found or something similar like:
public_html/system/library/db.php(31): DB\MySQLi->__construct('localhost', 'databaseuser', 'dbpassword', 'databasename', '3306')

for safety reasons should be enough to deactivate display_errors and error_reporting from my server to avoid displaying this data in the users browser or need to take additional action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display_errors is for errors displayed openly on your website. You should set it to "off" such as: `display_errors = Off;`

error_reporting is used for you to keep track of errors in your log files instead. Some administrators like to leave this on in case they want to monitor any issues. So this setting can stay as: `error_reporting = E_ALL;`
However, if you wish to turn it off, you can set it instead to: `error_reporting(0);`

There are some more advanced settings/techniques for these items. However, for your purpose, this should be enough.